# Jackson doesn't serialize field defined by `def`

Tags: json, scala, jackson

Following the approach in [Easy JSON (un)marshalling in Scala with Jackson](https://coderwall.com/p/o--apg/easy-json-un-marshalling-in-scala-with-jackson), I have defined a `JsonUtil` class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationFeature, JsonNode, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper

object JsonUtil {
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
  mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS)

  def toJsonNode[T](elem: T): JsonNode = mapper.valueToTree(elem)
}
```

And now I want to serialize a class containing an `Int` and another `Int` with double the value:

```
import JsonUtil.toJsonNode

trait X {
  def x: Int
  def doubleX: Int = x * 2
}

case class Three() extends X {
  val x = 3
}

println(toJsonNode(Three()))
// {"x":3}
println(Three().doubleX)
// 6
```

I realize that Jackson might not recognize a field defined by `def`. However, defining `doubleX` by `def` instead of `val` ensures that its value is always correct. Any workaround to make `def` and Jackson compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`def` doesn't define a field, it's a method. Just annotate the `def` with [`@JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) and Jackson should consider it as a getter for a "logical property".